# Cannot get OpenGL ES Android plugin to show drawn vertex array

Tags: android, flutter, opengl-es, egl

I am attempting to write a Flutter plugin for Android to allow me to directly write pixels using a `Texture`, so I need to make a `SurfaceTexture` available, and I want to be able to draw arbitrary pixel data to it using a single textured quad. For now, for debugging, I am simply trying to draw a single cyan triangle over a magenta background to verify my vertices are being drawn correctly, but it appears they are not. The `glClear` call is doing what I expect, as the magenta background is being shown instead of the black color that would otherwise be behind it, and I can change that color by changing what I pass to `glClearColor`, so in some way, the texture is being rendered, but I see no evidence that calling `glDrawArrays` is accomplishing anything. The code containing all of my interfacing with OpenGL ES is in the file below, and the `drawTextureToCurrentSurface` method is where both `glClear` and `glDrawArrays` are being called:

```
class EglContext {

    companion object {
        // Pass through position and UV values
        val vertexSource = """
            #version 300 es
            precision mediump float;
            
            /*layout(location = 0)*/ in vec2 position;
            /*layout(location = 1)*/ in vec2 uv;
            
            out vec2 uvOut;
            
            void main() {
                gl_Position = vec4(position, -0.5, 1.0);
                uvOut = uv;
            }
        """.trimIndent()

        // Eventually get the texture value, for now, just make it cyan so I can see it
        val fragmentSource = """
            #version 300 es
            precision mediump float;
            
            in vec2 uvOut;
            
            out vec4 fragColor;
            
            uniform sampler2D tex;
            
            void main() {
                vec4 texel = texture(tex, uvOut);
                // Effectively ignore the texel without optimizing it out
                fragColor = texel * 0.0001 + vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            }
        """.trimIndent()

        var glThread: HandlerThread? = null
        var glHandler: Handler? = null
    }

    private var display = EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY
    private var context = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT
    private var config: EGLConfig? = null

    private var vertexBuffer: FloatBuffer
    private var uvBuffer: FloatBuffer
    //private var indexBuffer: IntBuffer

    private var defaultProgram: Int = -1
    private var uniformTextureLocation: Int = -1
    private var vertexLocation: Int = -1
    private var uvLocation: Int = -1

    var initialized = false

    private fun checkGlError(msg: String) {
        val errCodeEgl = EGL14.eglGetError()
        val errCodeGl = GLES30.glGetError()
        if (errCodeEgl != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS || errCodeGl != GLES30.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            throw RuntimeException(
                "$msg - $errCodeEgl(${GLU.gluErrorString(errCodeEgl)}) : $errCodeGl(${
                    GLU.gluErrorString(
                        errCodeGl
                    )
                })"
            )
        }
    }

    init {
        // Flat square
        // Am I allocating and writing to these correctly?
        val vertices = floatArrayOf(-1f, -1f, 1f, -1f, -1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
        vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.size * 4).asFloatBuffer().also {
            it.put(vertices)
            it.position(0)
        }
        val uv = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
        uvBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uv.size * 4).asFloatBuffer().also {
            it.put(uv)
            it.position(0)
        }
        // Not being used until I can figure out what's currently not working
        /*val indices = intArrayOf(0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3)
        indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.size * 4).asIntBuffer().also {
            it.position(0)
            it.put(indices)
            it.position(0)
        }*/
        if (glThread == null) {
            glThread = HandlerThread("flutterSoftwareRendererPlugin")
            glThread!!.start()
            glHandler = Handler(glThread!!.looper)
        }
    }

    // Run OpenGL code on a separate thread to keep the context available
    private fun doOnGlThread(blocking: Boolean = true, task: () -> Unit) {
        val semaphore: Semaphore? = if (blocking) Semaphore(0) else null
        glHandler!!.post {
            task.invoke()
            semaphore?.release()
        }
        semaphore?.acquire()
    }

    fun setup() {
        doOnGlThread {
            Log.d("Native", "Setting up EglContext")

            display = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
            if (display == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
                Log.e("Native", "No display")
                checkGlError("Failed to get display")
            }
            val versionBuffer = IntArray(2)
            if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(display, versionBuffer, 0, versionBuffer, 1)) {
                Log.e("Native", "Did not init")
                checkGlError("Failed to initialize")
            }
            val configs = arrayOfNulls<EGLConfig>(1)
            val configNumBuffer = IntArray(1)
            var attrBuffer = intArrayOf(
                EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                //EGL14.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8,
                //EGL14.EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1,
                //EGL14.EGL_SAMPLES, 4,
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
            )
            if (!EGL14.eglChooseConfig(
                    display,
                    attrBuffer,
                    0,
                    configs,
                    0,
                    configs.size,
                    configNumBuffer,
                    0
                )
            ) {
                Log.e("Native", "No config")
                checkGlError("Failed to choose a config")
            }
            if (configNumBuffer[0] == 0) {
                Log.e("Native", "No config")
                checkGlError("Got zero configs")
            }
            Log.d("Native", "Got Config x${configNumBuffer[0]}: ${configs[0]}")
            config = configs[0]
            attrBuffer = intArrayOf(
                EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL14.EGL_NONE
            )
            context = EGL14.eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrBuffer, 0)
            if (context == EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
                Log.e("Native", "Failed to get any context")
                checkGlError("Failed to get context")
            }

            Log.d("Native", "Context = $context\n 'Current' = ${EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext()}")

            initialized = true
        }
    }

    // Called by my plugin to get a surface to register for Texture widget
    fun buildSurfaceTextureWindow(surfaceTexture: SurfaceTexture): EGLSurface {
        var _surface: EGLSurface? = null
        doOnGlThread {
            val attribBuffer = intArrayOf(EGL14.EGL_NONE)
            val surface =
                EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, surfaceTexture, attribBuffer, 0)
            if (surface == EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
                checkGlError("Obtained no surface")
            }
            EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context)
            Log.d("Native", "New current context = ${EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext()}")
            if (defaultProgram == -1) {
                defaultProgram = makeProgram(
                    mapOf(
                        GLES30.GL_VERTEX_SHADER to vertexSource,
                        GLES30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER to fragmentSource
                    )
                )
                uniformTextureLocation = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(defaultProgram, "tex")
                vertexLocation = GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(defaultProgram, "position")
                uvLocation = GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(defaultProgram, "uv")
                Log.d("Native", "Attrib locations $vertexLocation, $uvLocation")
                checkGlError("Getting uniform")
            }
            _surface = surface
        }
        return _surface!!
    }

    fun makeCurrent(eglSurface: EGLSurface, width: Int, height: Int) {
        doOnGlThread {
            GLES30.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
            if (!EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(display, eglSurface, eglSurface, context)) {
                checkGlError("Failed to make surface current")
            }
        }
    }

    fun makeTexture(width: Int, height: Int): Int {
        var _texture: Int? = null
        doOnGlThread {
            val intArr = IntArray(1)
            GLES30.glGenTextures(1, intArr, 0)
            checkGlError("Generate texture")
            Log.d("Native", "${EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext()} ?= ${EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT}")
            val texture = intArr[0]
            Log.d("Native", "Texture = $texture")
            GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
            checkGlError("Bind texture")
            val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4)
            GLES30.glTexImage2D(
                GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                0,
                GLES30.GL_RGBA,
                width,
                height,
                0,
                GLES30.GL_RGBA,
                GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                buffer
            )
            checkGlError("Create texture buffer")
            _texture = texture
        }
        return _texture!!
    }

    private fun compileShader(source: String, shaderType: Int): Int {
        val currentContext = EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext()
        val noContext = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT
        val shaderId = GLES30.glCreateShader(shaderType)
        Log.d("Native", "Created $shaderId\nContext $currentContext vs $noContext")
        checkGlError("Create shader")
        if (shaderId == 0) {
            Log.e("Native", "Could not create shader for some reason")
            checkGlError("Could not create shader")
        }
        GLES30.glShaderSource(shaderId, source)
        checkGlError("Setting shader source")
        GLES30.glCompileShader(shaderId)
        val statusBuffer = IntArray(1)
        GLES30.glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GLES30.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, statusBuffer, 0)
        val shaderLog = GLES30.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId)
        Log.d("Native", "Compiling shader #$shaderId : $shaderLog")

        if (statusBuffer[0] == 0) {
            GLES30.glDeleteShader(shaderId)
            checkGlError("Failed to compile shader $shaderId")
        }
        return shaderId
    }

    private fun makeProgram(sources: Map<Int, String>): Int {
        val currentContext = EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext()
        val noContext = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT
        val program = GLES30.glCreateProgram()
        Log.d("Native", "Created $program\nContext $currentContext vs $noContext")
        checkGlError("Create program")
        sources.forEach {
            val shader = compileShader(it.value, it.key)
            GLES30.glAttachShader(program, shader)
        }
        val linkBuffer = IntArray(1)
        GLES30.glLinkProgram(program)
        GLES30.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES30.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkBuffer, 0)
        if (linkBuffer[0] == 0) {
            GLES30.glDeleteProgram(program)
            checkGlError("Failed to link program $program")
        }
        return program
    }

    // Called to actually draw to the surface. When fully implemented it should draw whatever is
    // on the associated texture, but for now, to debug, I just want to verify I can draw vertices,
    // but it seems I cannot?
    fun drawTextureToCurrentSurface(texture: Int, surface: EGLSurface) {
        doOnGlThread {
            // Verify I have a context
            val currentContext = EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext()
            val noContext = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT
            Log.d("Native", "Drawing, Context = $currentContext vs $noContext")

            checkGlError("Just checking first")
            GLES30.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 1f, 1f)
            GLES30.glClearDepthf(1f)
            GLES30.glDisable(GLES30.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
            GLES30.glClear(GLES30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GLES30.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            checkGlError("Clearing")

            GLES30.glUseProgram(defaultProgram)
            checkGlError("Use program")

            GLES30.glActiveTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE0)
            checkGlError("Activate texture 0")
            GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
            checkGlError("Bind texture $texture")
            GLES30.glUniform1i(uniformTextureLocation, 0)
            checkGlError("Set uniform")

            GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation)
            vertexBuffer.position(0)
            GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer)
            Log.d("Native", "Bound vertices (shader=$defaultProgram)")
            checkGlError("Attribute 0")

            GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvLocation)
            uvBuffer.position(0)
            GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(uvLocation, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, uvBuffer)
            checkGlError("Attribute 1")

            //indexBuffer.position(0)
            //GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, 4, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffer)
            // I would expect to get a triangle of different color than the background
            GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3)
            GLES30.glFinish()
            checkGlError("Finished GL")

            EGL14.eglSwapBuffers(display, surface)
            checkGlError("Swapped buffers")
        }
    }
...currently unused other methods
}
```

The general flow of the above code is that the `init` block executes when initializing the context, of which there is only one. `setup` is called when the plugin is registered, and `buildSurfaceTextureWindow` is called when initializing a `SurfaceTexture` for a Flutter `Texture`. The first time this is called, it compiles the shaders. When the plugin wants to render the texture, it calls `makeCurrent` then `drawTextureToCurrentSurface`, which is where the magenta background becomes visible but without any cyan triangle. Calls to GL functions are done in a separate thread using `doOnGlThread`.

If you need to see all of the code including the full plugin implementation and example app using it, [I have it on Github](https://github.com/cppietime/flutter-sw-rend), but as far as I can tell the above code should be the only relevant region to not seeing any geometry rendered in the effectively hardcoded color from my fragment shader.

tl;dr My background color from `glClear` shows up on screen, but my expected result of calling `glDrawArrays`, a cyan triangle, does not, and I am trying to understand why.

Comment: Firstly, I would advise you to separate the "context" code from rendering code. Then you can try your rendering code within `GLSurfaceView`, where the context is prepared for you. If everything works well, then look for the problem in your "context code". Sure you got the idea.

Comment: @frumle is it even possible to use a `GLSurfaceView` within a flutter application? The reason I'm using the `SurfaceTexture` is so it can be used  as a `Texture` widget

Comment: Can't you run your rendering code in a simple Android application? What you are doing are relatively low level things. I am not sure that flutter is good choice for this, cause even native sdk could contain a bug. It is possible that the problem not even in your code. See eg my old question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63812207/problem-when-resizing-and-resuming-pausing-glsurfaceview

Comment: @frumle Good point. Yeah even just the rendering code in an Android application is failing to display anything different. I see my background color but no geometry

Comment: You are already halfway to the goal :). Try to make your rendering code work on Android. Haven't worked with GLES 3.0 yet, but I think you should write `gl_FragColor` instead of `fragColor`. Check, please, if this is the problem.

Comment: And go not declare `gl_FragColor`. It should be available for you inside the fragment shader like `gl_Position` inside the vertex one (which is correct in your code).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to call `.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())` on my buffers. Without this, the vertex array data is not set up properly. Also I needed to set `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...)` for `GL_TEXTURE_MAG/MIN_FILTER` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S/T`. Without that, all textures are all-black